# HTML5 Equivalent to Silverlight RichTextBox?

Tags: html, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I've had some experience with the new `RichTextBox` in Silverlight 4 and I was wondering if anyone knew of a good equivalent/example in HTML5?

I've seen this [pretty cool example](http://semantic-editor.org/try_it/) with `contentEditable`, but I'm wondering if there are better solutions for creating a rich text editor from scratch out there? I'm really just in my research phase right now and want an editor that can be used on multiple platforms (since I won't be able to run my Silverlight App in iOS, etc). I'd prefer not using 3rd party software/solutions, I'm just looking into the HTML5 options similar to whats out there for Silverlight.

Comment: Check out this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259112/is-there-a-cross-browser-jquery-contenteditable-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of HTML-equivs such as http://ckeditor.com/.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's kind of what I'm looking for, but not really. I guess I could re-word my question. I'm looking for a way to create a rich text editor in HTML5 from scratch because buying an enterprise license is out of the question and it must be fully customizable, etc. I'm looking into HTML5 options similar to that of the RichtextBox in SL4.