# Is there a cross-browser jQuery contentEditable library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin / library that makes the contentEditable attribute work properly in all major browsers (I could even go without IE6). I don't need a full WYSIWYG editor solution because I want to build my own – however I'm focusing on user experience so I'd prefer a "plug and play" solution.

I only need to access the editor features through code (API-like), I'm building the user interface myself.

Comment: What do you want besides `$('div').attr('contentEditable', '')` ?

Comment: No `class="apple-style-span"`, no blurbs concerning newlines etc. I'm thinking of TinyMCE stripped down to its API.

Comment: Well, in terms of compatibility back to IE6, it was actually [IE 5.5 that introduced it](http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable). I'd be interested to see if there's a suite that matches capabilities between browsers, although for most of the basic functionality they've always seemed pretty uniform to me. (Edit: Point noted on newlines.)

Comment: Surprisingly enough, it's Mozilla having a poorly implemented `contentEditable` feature. IE and Safari should be fine.

Comment: @Daniel: Each browser has its own quirks and flaws with contenteditable-related functionality. Mozilla has its share, but I'm not sure it's worse than WebKit or IE.

Comment: @Daniel: Webkit is really horrible in the way that it deals with contentEditable. I'll take IE8 and Firefox without thinking a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Aloha](https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/) is a feature-complete and polished editor component using contentEditable. It uses [jQuery UI](http://aloha-editor.org/blog/2012/07/aloha-editor-goes-jquery-and-gplv2/).

Comment: Thanks, Aloha has gone jQuery native. http://aloha-editor.org/blog/2012/07/aloha-editor-goes-jquery-and-gplv2/

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using **WYSIHAT** (http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1330-introducing-wysihat-an-eventually-better-open-source-wysiwyg-editor, https://github.com/37signals/wysihat).

It's Prototype-based (yeah, I know, not jQuery), but it's exactly the kind of "library" I needed. I can build my own toolbars and even own commands with ease.

jQuery can be integrated in `.noConflict`-mode.

Comment: There's a jquery port. Its main branch at the time of commenting breaks IE, but [there is a working branch](https://github.com/debaasmedia/jq-wysihat).

Comment: This fork of jq-wysihat looks better maintained: https://github.com/carlocapocasa/jq-wysihat

Answer (score 2):

Tinymce allows you to build the interface yourself and is jquery compatible.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php

If you desire to build everything yourself(like from scratch), there will probably be a lot of cross browser debugging needed.  Some browsers like IE support exexCommand others don't and you now the typical javascript bugs that come with developing a library.

I would just delete what you don't need of off tinymce, if you want efficiency and speedy.

Comment: Good point! However, I need `div`s and other DOM elements spread across the whole HTML document editable. Having >20 instances of TinyMCE on one site would be overkill and even slow down the whole performance.

Comment: WYSIHAT by 37signals looks quite nice – it's Prototype-based though but jQuery's .noConflict() mode could do the job.

Comment: Yeah I typically wrap all jQuery code in closures `(function($){})(jQuery);` to avoid any possible conflict.  jQuery is amazing.

Comment: This one looks more similar to what you need http://www.wymeditor.org/demo/

Comment: Actually all major browsers support `execCommand()`.

Comment: @Tim Define works :0 http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html   Because I definitely wouldn't say javascript (generally speaking) just works cross browser. %)

Comment: @Lime: I'm certainly not saying `execCommand()` works identically cross-browser, and indeed editable content is one area where browsers do differ significantly. However, `execCommand()` is implemented with a similar list of commands in all the major browsers.